# Refering to a key and not to a value when parsing JSON

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I got this JSON example:

```
"rates":{
"CAD":0.3917637839,
"HKD":2.3359708775,
"ISK":40.1951614126,
}
```

I managed to get my flow to send me back X value based on key, but I dont want to call the flow each time the user changes currency, I'd rather call it once at the beginning to loop and gather all of the keys and values into an array and send it back to powerapps.

And onto my problem!
because powerapps can only respond back with string and not an array, i wanted to do something like:
`Key1-Value1|Key2-Value2...` and then parse it on powerapps to create the collection.

but when I try to create an apply 'apply for each' with the json values, i can only refer to values!
an example would be: `body('JSON')?['rates'][CAD]` to get the CAD currency.

How can I get the *key* value of the current item?

some sample code from the current flow that gets currency and returns value:
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HotAr.png)

Thanks in advance!